# timepicker guardarlo en mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-timepicker

Estoy usando la librería  timepicker de Jquery, ya que el campo `input="time"` en html no me sirve porque da formato de 24hrs.

El problema que tengo es que el timepicker me da los valores por ejemplo 1:30PM.Asi es lo que yo quiero que se vea de esa manera. Pero como mi campo de la base de datos Mysql es de tipo time al tratar de insertar ese valor me da error.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect time value: '12:30 AM' for column 'hora_cita' at row 1

Hay alguna forma para que el usuario vea el formato de 12hra pero que al guardar transforme ese valor a formato de 24horas que usa el campo time?

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
$("#timepicker").timepicker({
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm p',
  interval: 15,
  dynamic: true,
  dropdown: true,
  scrollbar: true

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-2">
  <label for="hora_cita" class="requerido">Hora</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hora_cita" id="timepicker" placeholder="Hota Cita" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario hacer el cambio en *Javascript*, utiliza la función [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) de *PHP* para separar los elementos y analizar lo que se debe hacer para convertir formato de 12 a 24 horas:

```
function hora12a24($hora) {
    // La hora viene separada por espacio de AM/PM
    list($time, $ampm) = explode(' ', $hora);
    // Horas y minutos están separadas por :
    list($hh, $mm) = explode(':', $time);
    if($ampm == 'AM' && $hh == 12) {
        // Si es AM y la hora es 12, debe ser 00
        $hh = '00';
    } elseif($ampm == 'PM' && $hh < 12) {
        // Si es PM y la hora es < 12, 1 PM = 13, 11 PM = 23
        $hh += 12;
    }
    // Devolver con segundos incluídos
    return "$hh:$mm:00";
}

echo hora12a24('01:30 PM') . '<br>'; // 13:30:00
echo hora12a24('12:25 AM') . '<br>'; // 00:25:00
echo hora12a24('10:45 AM') . '<br>'; // 10:45:00
echo hora12a24('11:06 PM');          // 23:06:00
```

En los comentarios se explica qué hace cada paso.

Comment: gracias amigo no lo hice de esta forma pero me diste la idea de hacerlo desde php, pensaba que era desde el javascript que debía hacer la conversión. utilice lo siguiente para transformar la hora `date("H:i", strtotime($request->get('hora_cita')));` y ya me lo convierte a formato 24hrs